# Image cut in windows - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

When I view an image, it disappears depending on the size of my window.

By default the images are cut but if I enlarged the window as the images appear
[image]

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1716*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="889*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Image x:Name="img1" Margin="97,237,1054,911.4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="77" Height="147" Canvas.ZIndex="99"/>
<Image x:Name="img2" Margin="301,237,850,911.4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="77" Height="147" Canvas.ZIndex="99"/>
<Image x:Name="img3" Margin="539,237,612,911.4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="77" Height="147" Canvas.ZIndex="99"/>

<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="13,2,9.8,10.4" MaxHeight="200"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock x:Name="text2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Maison 2" Height="31" Width="77" Background="#FFDDDDDD" Padding="8"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="text1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Maison 1" Height="31" Width="77" Background="#FFDDDDDD" Padding="8"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Resultat3" Height="31" Width="960" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Padding="8"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Resultat2" Height="31" Width="960" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Padding="8"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="text3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Maison 3" Height="31" Width="77" Background="#FFDDDDDD" Padding="8"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Resultat1" Height="31" Width="960" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Padding="8"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

I just want to display images correctly. An idea ?

**EDIT**

Problem solved using the Canvas

Comment: *"I just want to display images correctly..."* <- define "correctly"? Can you show what outcome you are looking for? It is unclear what you're asking

Comment: You're placing the Image controls at absolute positions by setting their margins. Replace that by a proper layout.

Answer (score 0):

It seems obvious from your markup that you have used the designer 'drag and drop' to create your UI. That approach is quick, but highly unresponsive. Your UI will always be static, irrespective of the size of your app's Window.

I suggest you create your UI with XAML instead. Learning a few basic controls and their common properties will also help. If you are a beginner to XAML, you'll easily find plenty of resources online.

What you can do here is wrap your `Image` controls inside a `Grid` like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image x:Name="img1" Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="177" Width="77"  Stretch="Fill" />
    <Image x:Name="img2" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Height="177" Width="77" Stretch="Fill" />
    <Image x:Name="img3" Grid.Column="2" Width="100" Height="177" Width="77" Stretch="Fill" />
</Grid>
```